# Using NOW() between 2 dates

Tags: mysql

Got a query that looks pretty darn simple, but returns no results when I should be getting some. The issue is the last part where I want to make sure that I'm getting stuff that is between the launch and expire dates.

```
SELECT *
FROM PTD_PartiesDecorations
WHERE PTDbDisabled = 0
AND PTDPTCiComponent = 1
AND NOW() BETWEEN PTDdLaunch AND PTDdExpire
```

Comment: what is the data type of the PTDdLaunch and PTDdExpire columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `PTDdExpire` is null, you'll get no results.

If that's the case try this:

```
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN PTDdLaunch AND ifnull(PTDdExpire, '2099-01-01)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would make it impossible for an index on PTDdExpire to be used.